# Escrever arquivo CSV em determinada linha passada por parametro c#

Tags: c#, arquivo, csv

Como escrever em um arquivo CSV, em uma determinada linha que receberei por parâmetro, exemplo do começo do código:

```
 public void EscreverCSV(string caminho, int linha, string mensagemErro)

    {
        using (StreamWriter wt = new StreamWriter(caminho))
        {


        }
    }
```

Comment: linha da onde ? inteiro ? pra q essa mensagemErro ?

Comment: eu tenho um arquivo CSV que contem diversas linhas separada por ; (ponto e virgula), eu quero chamar esse método e falar para ele adicione um texto ( o parâmetro mensagemErro)  na linha ( numero passado por parâmetro também)

Comment: exemplo: quero que na linha 5 seja adicionado a mensagem "não foi inserido"

Comment: Então seria editar, ou adicionar um campo na linha i do arquivo CSV informado

Comment: exatamente Rovann, poderia por gentileza me ajudar nisso?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode ler o arquivo, armazenar cada linha em uma `List<>`, buscar a linha que precisa alterar, e escrever no arquivo novamente.

Lembrando que o índice das linhas começa no 0.

Segue o código comentado:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
```

...

```
public static string EscreveCSV(string caminho, int linha, string mensagem)
{
    //Só continua se o arquivo informado existir
    if (File.Exists(caminho))
    {
        //lista que irá armazenar cada linha do arquivo
        List<string> linhas = new List<string>();   


        using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(caminho, Encoding.Default))
        {
            string sLinha = null;
            while ((sLinha = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                linhas.Add(sLinha); //adiciona cada linha do arquivo à lista
            }

            tr.Close();    
        }

        //Só continua se o arquivo ter um número maior de linhas informadas
        if (linhas.Count > linha)
        {
            linhas[linha] += ";" + mensagem; //adiciona a mensagem informada ao final da linha

            using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(caminho, false, Encoding.Default))
            {
                foreach (string l in linhas)
                {
                    tw.WriteLine(l); //escreve no arquivo novamente
                }

                tw.Close();
            }

            return "Arquivo Escrito com sucesso"; //mensagem de retorno
        }
        else
        {
            return "Arquivo Não possui a linha informada";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return "Arquivo não existe";    
    }
}
```

coloquei no .NetFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ld7vTQ

Comment: Rovann, deu erro na leitura do aquivo, diz que o arquivo ja esta sendo usado por outro processo, acredito que seja porque foi aberto no StreamWrite ai quando tentamos fazer a leitura da mesma planilha da o erro.

Comment: o `StreamReader` e `StreamWriter` ao final do processo são fechados, verifique se o arquivo não está aberto em outro programa no seu computador

Comment: qual linha exatamente ocorre o erro ?

Comment: já verifiquei  e nao esta aberto, o erro da na na seguinte linha:

Comment: using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(caminho, Encoding.Default))

Comment: editei o comentario pois confundir a linha do erro, agora esta certo, é essa linha citada acima que acontece o erro.

Comment: o C# então não consegue nem mesmo ler o arquivo, certamente ele está sendo usado, tente fazer uma cópia do arquivo, e testar com ela

Comment: fiz isso tmb, depois fechei a conexao do StreamWriter (  tw.Close();) para testar e "funcionou"  só que ai não conseguimos que funcione como esperamos.

Comment: mas o `TextWriter` está depois, não está fazendo muito sentido isso. fez alguma alteração no código ?

Comment: Cara na primeira tentativa acho que copiei do dotnetfiddle.net ai fiz mais uma tentativa copiando o seu código aqui, parece que o wt.Close() nao estava liberando o arquivo ai coloquei logo abaixo o wt.Dispose e funcionou, cara muito obrigado pela ajuda, estava quebrando a cabeça aqui.

Comment: como estou usando o `using` não é necessário o `Dispose` mas, se conseguiu fazer funcionar, que bom, não se esqueça de marcar como resposta. Obrigado @JhonatasSilva